# Making buttons visible on uitableview swipe

Tags: ios

I have a uitableview in which I have added two custom buttons(accept/reject) also styled them and also detecting from which row buttons are pressed. Now I want them to be hidden by default when user swipe then they appear with delete button like animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you need:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *deleteRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureToShowDeleteButton:)];
            deleteRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
            [deleteRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
            [cell addGestureRecognizer:deleteRecognizer];
            [deleteRecognizer release];
```

now add a method 'gestureToShowDeleteButton' in your view controller and show the delete button in this method with the animation...

this will go into gestureToShowDeleteButton method....

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay: 0.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{ 
    [btnDeleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 128, 55)]; 
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){ }
    ];
```

initialize the button with frame (288,10,0,55), provided the dimensions of your button is 128x55....

hope it helps... ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am not working on delete, i am working on custom buttons, I want my custom buttons to appear like uitableview delete button like animation

Comment: yes, u can show your custom delete button with animation! in the same way as apple do... have a look at my answer that I edited...

Comment: Thanks for reply, can u plz send a working snippet on my email..this code is bit confusing me. Email is on my  profile. Thanks

Comment: mail sent... check ur spam if u dont get it till now... ;)